# Unsetting an exported environment variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am using export to set an environment variable.

```
export OPCON_VERBOS=${vb}
```

How can I then unset it later so that it stops being define anymore?

Comment: I think `unset OPCON_VERBOS` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unset OPCON_VERBOS
```

or

```
OPCON_VERBOS=
```

or

```
OPCON_VERBOS=""
```

The `unset` removes the environment variable (and its value).  The others keep the environment variable, but set its value to the empty string, which in many use cases has the same result as removing the value.

Comment: It should be `unset OPCON_VERBOS`. If you use `env | grep OPCON_VERBOS` the variable will not be anymore, but if you use `OPCON_VERBOS=` or `OPCON_VERBOS=""` and check with `env | grep OPCON_VERBOS` the variable will still exist.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Yes.  Isn't that what I said?  "The others keep the environment variable but removes its value."

Comment: Oh, yes!! I did not realize! Sorry friend.

Comment: Technically, `OPCON_VERBOS=` doesn't remove the value, but sets *the empty string* as its value. Removing a value is unsetting. A variable can be exported without being set (without being given a value) with `unset -v var; export var`. In that case, if you later give a value to the variable, `var=that-value` will be passed to the environment of executed commands. `unset -v var` unsets and also undeclares. Beware in bash, `unset var` would unset the `var` *function* if the `var` *variable* wasn't set, so it's a good habit to use `-v` to avoid unsetting functions by mistake.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you; I'm having trouble finding a script use case where the difference between the value being removed and the value being set to an empty string makes a difference.  I'm not finding one besides `env | grep VARNAME`.  But perhaps it's because I'm using Bash.  Does zsh or another shell show different behavior for `VARNAME=` vs. `unset VARNAME`?